# @JsonIdentityInfo serialization of items

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm trying to serialize relations using @JsonItentityInfo to avoid circular references. I've created a test to try test the result of the serialization, and I've found that jackson is not behaving as I expected. The serialization in not what I though it would be and, in fact, when I try to desarialize the serializated object, an exception is thrown. The code I'm using is:

```
public class Test {
    
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public static class A {
        private final String id;
        private final String name;
        private final B b;
        
        public A(final String id, final String name, final B b) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.b = b;
        }
        
        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public B getB() {
            return this.b;
        }

    }
    
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public static class B {

        private final String id;
        private final String name;
        
        public B(final String id, final String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new A("1", "a", new B("2", "b"))));
        } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To my understanding, the output should be

```
{"id":"1","name":"a","b":"2"}
```

but the test returns

```
{"id":"1","name":"a","b":{"id":"2","name":"b"}}
```

In fact, when trying to read the serialized string jackson throws an exception. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all for your help

**Edit**: The example was not complete. The object should be enveloped in another object, so the two of them are serialized.

```
package lvillap.deliverytoolsserver.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {

    private final A a;
    private final B b;

    public Test(final A a, final B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return this.a;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return this.b;
    }

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public static class A {

        private final String id;
        private final String name;
        @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
        @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
        private final B b;

        public A(final String id, final String name, final B b) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.b = b;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public B getB() {
            return this.b;
        }

    }

    public static class B {

        private final String id;
        private final String name;

        public B(final String id, final String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            final B b = new B("2", "b");
            final A a = new A("1", "a", b);
            System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new Test(a, b)));
        } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When implemented this way, the result is the expected:
{"a":{"id":"1","name":"a","b":"2"},"b":{"id":"2","name":"b"}}

Thank you all for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under default circumstances, you get exactly what you you should get.

What you can do is change you `class A` like follows.

*Note that I have changed `getB()` method. It no longer return instance of `class B`. It returns `id` attribute of that `class B` instance.*

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public static class A {
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final B b;

    public A(final String id, final String name, final B b) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return this.b.id;
    }

}
```

You can also create a custom serializer for `class B` as well.

Comment: You are exactly right, I'll edit the question, because it is not complete. A and B should be inside another object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want

```
{"id":"1","name":"a","b":"2"}
```

then you change `private final B b;` to `private final String b;`, remove class B and change the code

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new A("1", "a", "2"));
```

You can also remove  `@JsonIdentityInfo`

I think everything is kind of straightforward, Object Java will be converted to Object json, so when you include `class B` in `class A` as a field then you have nested json object.

Comment: You are exactly right, I'll edit the question, because it is not complete. A and B should be inside another object.